# CRON Job To Execute Command On Low Memory

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron, memory

I have a situation where I may need to execute an SAP command line tool `hdbsql` when memory gets too low (to help clean out the HANA table cache).

How I can best approach this?  I did have an idea to extract the free memory value from the `top` command (or get free/max*100 to get a %, which is better) in a shell script scheduled using `crontab`, but I cannot find anything on a possible approach on this anywhere, so I cannot even start anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `awk` to calculate the percentage and the [`test`](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html) utillity to determine if the value exceeds 90%, for example. The cronjob could look like this:

```
/usr/bin/test 90 -le $(/usr/bin/awk '$1=="MemTotal:"{t=$2} $1=="MemFree:"{f=$2} END{printf "%d", (t-f)/(t/100)}' /proc/meminfo) && command-to-cleanup
```

The `awk` part extracts the needed values out of `/proc/meminfo`, and then calculates the percentage of used memory. The `test` utillity checks if 90 is is less or equal (`-le`) to the calculated value. The part after the `&&` would then be your tool that cleans up the memory (`.. && command-to-cleanup`). That cronjob can run every minute, for example:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/test 90 -le $(/usr/bin/awk '$1=="MemTotal:"{t=$2} $1=="MemFree:"{f=$2} END{printf "%d", (t-f)/(t/100)}' /proc/meminfo) && command-to-cleanup
```

Comment: In crontab, "%" need be escape:
* * * * *   /usr/bin/test 90 -le $(/usr/bin/awk '$1=="MemTotal:"{t=$2} $1=="MemFree:"{f=$2} END{printf "\%d", (t-f)/(t/100)}' /proc/meminfo) && (/usr/bin/killall chrome)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the percentage of the free memory on a linux system is NOT a good indicator in this situation because of the way linux memory management works (memory is also used for buffering and caching, there's also swapping, etc) - plenty of info out there on the subject. Which means using such indicator would cause cleaning the cache earlier than actually necessary which I imagine comes with a price in overall performance.

I found that the percentage of swap used is usually a much better indication of the system being short on memory while taking all these into account: as long as it can still allocate memory it tipically won't use the swap.

As a bonus this doubles as a performance indicator as well - a system using over 4G of swap for example is usually barely crawling (think how much it takes to copy a 4G disk file from one place to another).

The swap info be found in **/proc/meminfo**, so the approach that chaos suggested can be adapted accordingly:

```
SwapTotal:      16777212 kB
SwapFree:       16777212 kB
```

You may need to experiment a bit to find out which swap usage percentage value is better fit for your particular case.